# unit test code for GWT classes using Junit

Tags: java, gwt, junit

I have developed Simple project using GWT, in application i have three different layers like, model, service, ui. UI is the one for GWT classes, I could able to test model, service using Junit code, but i am unable to do junit for UI, could you help me how i can write jUnit test cases for GWT classes. thanks your help..

Answer (score 2):

There is nice article about GWT JUnit testing at [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/intl/sk-SK/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideTesting.html) - which is good documentation to see-  that should help you getting started.

If you would like to see concrete example, you should follow StockWatcher exmaple from that tutorial, that has [another part about JUnit testing (step by step)](http://code.google.com/intl/sk-SK/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JUnit.html).

Comment: Thanks for response, by this i can test components, in my applciation there is RPC IMPL classes, which actually invoke the my spring beans which is defined in service layer, how can i test RPC impl classes, is there way? thanks for your help.

Comment: There is part about remote testing in the first link I posted.

Comment: Just one doubt, could you please clarify me to run this test case do i need to run application?